# Modified OAuthController.cs for SharePoint Addins

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-addin

[image]I need to create a middle layer application to pass the Session Id and AntiForgery Token to the Frontend/User of a SharePoint Addin. It seems that the OAuthController also takes care to store the Access token from SharePoint into Session state.

Has anybody modified the OAuthController.cs which is mainly used for Office 365 for authentication purposes for SharePoint Addins, or has more information about it? The only info I've found which explained the mechanism based on Office 365 is on a Channel9 vid.

UPDATE: So far I've managed to create a safe mechanism to create and pass via AJAX the AntiForgeryToken via System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery class  also see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/passing_anti-forgery_token_to_mvc_actions_using_ajax_post/archive/2014/06/30/passing-anti-forgery-token-to-mvc-actions-using-ajax-post.aspx) Microsoft blog post

What remains is passing some sort of Session Id from middle layer to client and retrieve on the middle layer the SharePointContext based on the Session Id. I thought I could recycle the cookie Token part of the AntiForgery mechanism but based on [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427386/system-web-helpers-antiforgery-cookietoken) reply it's not possible.